# The shell test operator of -eq not giving correct result

Tags: bash, shell

In below code, whatever the letter i pass to test , the result is all wrong.
Can someone help me, thanks.

bash# cat test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#Using eq
if [[ ${1^^} -eq "D" ]]
 then
 echo "Using eq: D"
else
 echo "Using eq: Not D"
fi

#Using ==
if [[ ${1^^} == "D" ]]
 then
 echo "Using ==: D"
else
 echo "Using ==: Not D"
fi
```

bash:# ./test.sh o

```
Using eq: D
Using ==: Not D
```

In a interactive shell, the result is still wrong:
bash # letter='o'
bash # if [[ ${letter^^} -eq 'D' ]]

```
> then
> echo "D"
> else
> echo "not D"
> fi
D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-eq` operator is defined for integers:

> INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html

So the results you are seeing are expected.